# Error while loading opencv_java4.so file by dynamic delivery feature

Tags: android, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror, dynamic-delivery

I am using dynamic delivery feature of Android because openCV make the app size too large. The problem is When I try to load the opencv by using `SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(this, "opencv_java4")`. I gives me this error.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>    E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.com, PID: 7470
>    E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc++_shared.so" not found
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1016)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1669)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(Unknown Source:0)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at org.opencv.com.example.com.TempActivity.onResume(TempActivity.kt:615)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1434)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7304)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3993)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4033)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1977)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6923)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>    E AndroidRuntime:        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)

My *onCreate* looks like this

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    try {
        SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(this, "opencv_java4")
    } catch (exception: Exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace()
    }
```

Then loading the **openCV** library inside *onResume*

```
 override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION, this, mLoaderCallback)
    } else {
        mLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS)
    }
}
```

This is my *defaultConfig* in gradle for **openCV** module.

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            cppFlags ""
            arguments "-DANDROID_ARM_NEON=TRUE",'-DANDROID_STL=c++_shared'
            targets "opencv_jni_shared"
        }
    }

    ndk {
        abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
    }
}
```

Some resource asked to make changes to CMakeList.txt & dummy.cpp file's

**CmakeList.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

# dummy target to bring libc++_shared.so into packages
add_library(opencv_jni_shared STATIC dummy.cpp)

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
    log-lib

    # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
    # you want CMake to locate.
    log)

    target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
    opencv_jni_shared

    # Links the target library to the log library
    # included in the NDK.
    ${log-lib})
```

**dummy.cpp**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
whatever(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject /* this */){
std::string hello = "Hello";
return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I was desperately in search of a solution when I stumbled upon this [Github issue](https://github.com/bkaradzic/bgfx/issues/1122#issuecomment-296380358).
So apparently Android was asking me to load *libc++_shared.so* file before I try to load *opencv_java4*.

This is the change I made to my Activity which was loading *opencv*

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    SplitCompat.installActivity(this)
//This is the line I added before loading "opencv_java4"
    SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(this, "c++_shared")

    SplitInstallHelper.loadLibrary(this, "opencv_java4")
}
```

And it worked!